# Does gravity violate the parity symmetry?

Tags: gravity, quantum-gravity, parity

I was naively thinking about gravitons and gravity.

It's OK, gravitons are hypothetical particles, so we can only speculate about certain questions. But a maybe strange thing came into my mind: are there unique gravitons or would they be like neutrinos?

I mean, will we have left-handed and right-handed gravitons?

So, is there some correlation between left-handed gravitons and right-handed gravitons?

Such correlations have spin $4$ if they involve gravitons moving along the same direction, and spin zero for gravitons moving with opposite directions. In the first case, the most immediate implication would be a degree of linear polarization for the tensor vacuum fluctuations, which could be seen by gravity wave detectors sensitive enough to probe the primordial background, its degree of polarization and anisotropies.

But in contrast, spin zero correlations would have an effect on the two point function of the 'cosmic microwave background' temperature and polarization, right?

So I thought that parity-violating gravity is naturally inspired by grand unification and the fact that the standard model is chiral and maximally violates parity.

But all of this might be a mere product of my mind, so please let me know if and how it makes any sense!

Comment: Gravitons are massless!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're making the common mistake of confusing helicity and chirality.  Chirality (the property that distinguishes left- and right-handed neutrinos) is a property of particles that transform as half-integer-spin representations of the Lorentz group, i.e. fermions.  Helicity, on the other hand, pertains to any particle which two possible spin polarization modes - i.e. spin-1/2 fermions *or* massless spin-1 or spin-2 bosons.  Gravitons (if they exist) have helicity but not chirality, so there is no such thing as "left-handed" or "right-handed" gravitons, any more than clockwise and counterclockwise-polarized photons are "left-" or "right-handed".  A given graviton's spin helicity should just be thought of as an "incidental" rather than a "defining" property of the particle species.

Comment: I think you did not understand my question.

Comment: @Alan Turing, tparker can edit his answer. The question is interesting, would you explain more what is the misunderstanding here? Hope that the question get a nice answer finally.

Comment: @AlanTuring Can you clarify it then? My answer seems to answer your question as I interpret it.

Comment: Seems to me it did answer the question, and answered it well.